# laravel take posts not registered by this user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can i take posts not registered by this user ? I create posts by This Code :

```
Auth::users()->post()->create($request->all());
```

I can get user posts with

```
users()->post()->all();
```

but i need to take count of posts created by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take all active posts of other users:

```
User::with(['posts' => function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', '<>', auth()->user()->id)
      ->where('status', 'active');
}])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

To count all posts of other users:

```
$count = Post::where('user_id', '<>', auth()->user()->id)->count();
```

Comment: Sorry how can i take posts where status == active ?